# Load dynamic content with puppeteer?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using this code to get the page data. It works but I get the data just one time.
The problem is that this data is updated lets say every second. I want to get it without reloading the page.
This is a simple example of what I want - http://novinite.win/clock.php
Is there a way to refresh the result without reloading the web page?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const url = process.argv[2];
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
     args: ['--no-sandbox']
  })

  const page = await browser.newPage();
  page.on('request', (request) => {
    console.log(`Intercepting: ${request.method} ${request.url}`);
    request.continue();
  });
  await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'load'});
  const html = await page.content();
  console.log(html);

  browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`await`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/await) a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) that logs the current [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent) every `1000` ms (1 second) with [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) and [resolves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve) after a set number of intervals (for example, `10` intervals):

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require( 'puppeteer' );

( async () =>
{
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    await page.goto( 'http://novinite.win/clock.php' );

    await new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) =>
    {
        let i = 0;

        const interval = setInterval( async () =>
        {
            console.log( await page.evaluate( () => document.getElementById( 'txt' ).textContent ) );

            if ( ++i === 10 )
            {
                clearInterval( interval );
                resolve( await browser.close() );
            }

        }, 1000 );
    });
})();
```

Example Result:

> 19:24:15
>
> 19:24:16
>
> 19:24:17
>
> 19:24:18
>
> 19:24:19
>
> 19:24:20
>
> 19:24:21
>
> 19:24:22
>
> 19:24:23
>
> 19:24:24